# Using AES-128 algorithm Encrypt Excel file in Java and Decrypt in C#

Tags: java, c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to Encrypt excel file in Java and Decrypt back in C# but the decrypted file is showing junk characters. I am able to Encrypt .txt and .docx file in Java and Decrypt back in C# without any issues.

Please check the code and let me know if i am doing any thing wrong ? Even let me know if anything needs to be added.

Java Code to Encrypt xls file

```
    // file to be encrypted
    File file = new File("D:\\SynchData\\output.xls");
    FileInputStream inFile = new FileInputStream(file);

    FileOutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream("D:\\SynchData\\output.dec");

    // password to encrypt the file
    String password = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";

    // password, iv and salt should be transferred to the other end
    // in a secure manner

    // salt is used for encoding
    // writing it to a file
    // salt should be transferred to the recipient securely
    // for decryption
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    /*SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
    secureRandom.nextBytes(salt);*/
    FileOutputStream saltOutFile = new FileOutputStream("salt.enc");
    saltOutFile.write(salt);
    saltOutFile.close();

    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, 1024, 128);
    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(keySpec);
    SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
    AlgorithmParameters params = cipher.getParameters();

    // iv adds randomness to the text and just makes the mechanism more
    // secure
    // used while initializing the cipher
    // file to store the iv
    FileOutputStream ivOutFile = new FileOutputStream("iv.enc");
    byte[] iv = params.getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class).getIV();
    log.info("iv length: "+iv.length);
    ivOutFile.write(iv);
    ivOutFile.close();

    //file encryption
    byte[] input = new byte[64];
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = inFile.read(input)) != -1) {
        byte[] output = cipher.update(input, 0, bytesRead);
        if (output != null)
            outFile.write(output);
    }

    byte[] output = cipher.doFinal();
    if (output != null)
        outFile.write(output);

    inFile.close();
    outFile.flush();
    outFile.close();

    log.info("File Encrypted.  exportEncryptFile");
```

C# Code to Decrypt

```
byte[] salt = new byte[16];

int iterations = 1024;
string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
{
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, salt,iterations);
    encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(16);
    encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
    using (FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
       // StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader(fsInput);
       //string str= strReader.ReadToEnd();

        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsInput, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            using (FileStream fsOutput = new FileStream(outputfilePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                int data;
                while ((data = cs.ReadByte()) != -1)
                {
                    fsOutput.WriteByte((byte)data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see nothing apparently wrong with it. Where are those junk bytes in the file (beginning/end/inbetween)? Are those additional bytes or do they replace some other bytes from the original file?

Comment: I don't see any attempt to ensure the encoding on both sides is the same. Perhaps that's the issue.

Comment: Also, where are you reading in the salt to decrypt equal to the one used to encrypt? I see you using a blank byte array.

Comment: Thanks guys for your reply. junk bytes are like this '¬é†V=<[]Lq"United States"'.

Comment: @Cory: this code is working fine for .txt and .docx file encryption and decryption

Comment: The way encoding works (in it's simplest form), is it takes character codes and maps them to the definition of that encoding. If you use two different encodings it's entirely possible for it to work for most characters, but not all. If you explicitly define the encoding, then everything should map fine. Perhaps the Excel file you're using contains characters that are outside the bounds of the encoding used to decrypt. I'm not sure, just tossing out ideas.

Comment: You should not compare documents, you should be comparing binary files. Create files with random data and size and then do a binary compare, see where it fails. If it doesn't fail, it's probably not the encryption.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I don't think he's comparing documents, I think he's getting corrupt data when trying to decrypt the original.

Comment: I meant: create random binary file, encrypt, decrypt, compare in case that's not sufficiently clear to everybody.

Comment: ^-- Ah, makes sense and is a good idea.

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies, my encryption and decryption code is working fine. I have changed the approach instated of excel i am using csv format file which is working good while encrypting in java and decrypting in c#.